# NOT using multiprocessing but get CUDA error on google colab while using PyTorch DataLoader

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, dataloader

I've cloned my GitHub repo into google colab and trying to load data using PyTorch's DataLoader.

```py
global gpu, device
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    gpu = True
    device = 'cuda:0'
    torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.FloatTensor')
    print("Using GPU")
else:
    gpu = False
    device = 'cpu'
    print("Using CPU")

data_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    #transforms.Resize(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.3112, 0.2636, 0.2047], [0.2419, 0.1972, 0.1554])
    ])
train_path = '/content/convLSTM/code/data/train/'
val_path = '/content/convLSTM/code/data/val/'
test_path = '/content/convLSTM/code/data/test/'

train_data = datasets.ImageFolder(root=train_path, transform=data_transforms)
val_data = datasets.ImageFolder(root=val_path, transform=data_transforms)
test_data = datasets.ImageFolder(root=test_path, transform=data_transforms)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    train_data,
    batch_size=18,
    num_workers=4,
    shuffle=False,
    pin_memory=True
    )

val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    val_data,
    batch_size=18,
    shuffle=False,
    num_workers=4,
    pin_memory=True
    )

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    test_data,
    batch_size=18,
    shuffle=False,
    num_workers=4,
    pin_memory=True
    )
for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
  print(batch_idx)
  if batch_idx==3:
    break
```

I'm getting the following error when I run the last for loop:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method
```

I tried `num_workers = 1` instead of `4` but the error persists. I'm not using any multiprocessing.

I also tried without setting `torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.FloatTensor')` but the error persists.

Python  : 3.6.8 | PyTorch : 1.3.1

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Instead of the whole dataloader i just tried doing ```test = next(iter(train_loader))``` and I'm getting the same exact error.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if you fixed it already but just in case someone else reads this, using n number of works activates pytorch multi processing. To disable it you need to have the default number of workers which is 0, not 1.

Try setting num_workers to 0 or using the [Torch Multiprocessing submodule](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/multiprocessing.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just try putting **num_workers=0**

```
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
```

*This solved the problem over Kaggle notebook*